# How to install `runhaskell`

Tags: haskell-stack

Where is `runhaskell` supposed to come from? It is not on my path, and when I run `stack build runhaskell`, I get *Unknown package: runhaskell*.

Answer (score 0):

`stack exec -- runhaskell --help` sounds like the right tool, though I'm not sure what the best answer is if another tool expects it to be available unqualified.